# ReactJS + LInk tag + event propagation

Tags: reactjs, events, react-router

Below is the part of my react component. I have DownloadIcon which should perform as expected but due to the link tag when I am clicking on the DownloadIcon it is following the routing address. Is there any ways to stop this kind of event propagation.

```js
if (hasData) {
  const inner = (
    <div className={bodyClass}>
      <MetricValue
        shift={metric[valueType.key === 'dollar' ? 'shift' : 'numAccountsChangePct']}
        threshold={metric.shiftThreshold}
        value={getCurrentValueFormatted(metric)}
      />
      {
        metric.canSeeOverviewTiles && metric.sscSelectionFlag && metric.metricId !== 1 &&
        <span className={styles.icon} onClick={() => alert('propagation')}>
          <DownloadIcon click={(e) => {e.stopPropagation();fetchAccountFile(metric);}}/>
        </span>
      }
      <GoalHistory history={metric.goals} isDays={metric.metricId === 1}/>
    </div>
  );
  return linkBase && metric.goals ? (
    <Link to={`${linkBase}${metric.metricId}`} onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
      {inner}
    </Link>
  ) : inner;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: @Joe C Can I stop the event propagation, so that my `<DownloadIcon/>` and `<Link/>` can work individually.

Comment: You should edit your question to make this clear.  I don't know the answer, but a clearly-placed question is more likely to attract those that do.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to use `Link` in that case. Use `<a href={linkURL} download>` instead. Source [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: thanks man. I replaced the   `<Link/>`  tag by `<a/> ` tag, but the issue is still there.

Comment: did you add `download` too?

Comment: Never mind, I added `e.preventDefault()` and it worked!